# Android Out of Memory error when postInvalidate

Tags: android

```
private void startGameTimeElapseThread(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        Date d = new Date();
        public void run() {
            while (true){
                try {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        this.wait(1000);    
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                postInvalidate();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

when i execute the above method it gives me the below error.

```
05-27 08:52:56.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12715): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-27 08:52:56.910: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12715): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
```

Does any one have any idea how to keep refreshing the screen every second without getting this error. ( in the canvas i draw a bitmap there. This says that bitmap causes this error )

Comment: How big is the bitmap? Also, I think MoonLander example had the correct way to do it.

Comment: Hi Dinesh, Is it possible for you to post the whole code so that we will go though that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an memory leak in your application. `postInvalidate()` causes the the whole `ViewGroup` to be redrawn. It's possible that a weak reference to your bitmap remains somewhere, or a weak reference to an Activity / View is present in the Heap which the GC can't free.

Since you have not posted much code, [here is a link](http://kohlerm.blogspot.com/2009/04/analyzing-memory-usage-off-your-android.html) on how to trace the leaks in your application.